# Windows 10 Auto Login doesn't work with November Update

Tags: auto-login, windows-10-v1511

After upgrading to `Windows 10 November update`, Windows no longer allows user to `auto-login` to any user account. I tried to setup the [Registry values](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-automatically-login-in-windows-10/), it didn't work. After the restart, all the values are being even deleted.

Any idea, how to enable `auto-login` in Windows 10 November update or workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Autologon.exe from sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/autologon.aspx) and this worked on my Windows 10 (Version 1511).

> Autologon enables you to easily configure Windows’ built-in autologon
>   mechanism. Instead of waiting for a user to enter their name and
>   password, Windows uses the credentials you enter with Autologon, which
>   are encrypted in the Registry, to log on the specified user
>   automatically.
>
> Autologon is easy enough to use. Just run autologon.exe, fill in the
>   dialog, and hit `Enable`. To turn off auto-logon, hit `Disable`.

Comment: any way to run this from `cmd` [Enable and Disable]. Automation is the key :)

Comment: it has commandline parameters. Check the page. I don't use Azure, so I have no idea why it fails for you.